# How to properly cast generic collections in Java?

Tags: java, casting, coding-style

Let's say that I have initially declared and defined a set of integers as follows:

```
Set<Integer> s = new TreeSet<>();
```

Now, later I want to use methods that are specific to a TreeSet. And imagine that I need to this a lot of times in my project. Which of following ways is considered a better practice to stick to?

1- Writing this before starting to use s, at the beginning of my method

```
s = (TreeSet) s;
```

2- Writing with the type included (again at the beginning of my method)

```
s = (TreeSet<Integer>) s;
```

3- Casting from Set to TreeSet only at times that I need to access a TreeSet specific method

```
Integer x = ((TreeSet)s).first();
```

Comment: Why did you make `s` a `Set` instead of a `TreeSet` in the first place, if you want to run `TreeSet` specific methods on `s`?

Comment: @azurefrog Or `NavigableSet`. / In general, don't lose type information you're going to need.

Comment: Yes, certain design principles like "Code to an Interface" are only principles and can be taken too far.  If you need a sub class, just declare and use the sub class, it's the right way to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you don't need to lose the context of the `Set` being a `TreeSet` after your declaration if it is important.

A `TreeSet` is-a `Set`, so you should be able to pass it around as a `Set`.

For example:

```
Set<Integer> getSetButDoSomethingSpecial() {
  TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
  //Do something specific to treeSet
  return treeSet;
}
```